# Why am I getting a "String indices must be integers" error when I am indicing a dictionary?

Tags: python, functional-programming, console, anonymous-function

I am trying to code a python console game framework. How I have designed it, there is a dictionary called game_state which is updated by a function passed into the loop function. After one iteration of the loop, it gives the error "String indices must be integers." The stack trace shows that the error is occuring at the line `if game_state["running"] == false`. When printing out game_state, it seems to be an empty string. Why is this happening, and what can I do to fix it?

```
def run_loop(calculate, draw, initial_state):
  fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
  old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
  tty.setraw(sys.stdin)
  game_state = initial_state
  with raw(sys.stdin):
    with nonblocking(sys.stdin):
      try:
        while True:
            try:
                c = sys.stdin.read(1)
                game_state = calculate(c, game_state)
                print_map(draw(game_state))
                if game_state["running"] == False:
                  break
            except IOError:
                print('not ready')
          
            time.sleep(.1)
      finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
  
def game(state, press):
  mut_state = state
  if press == "q":
    mut_state["running"] = False
  return mut_state
def display(game_state):
  return [["Yay!"]]
run_loop(game, display, {"running": True})
```

Comment: calculate must be returning a string not a dictionary like you expect...

Comment: `game_state` is apparently a string at the point that bit of code is executed. Have you tried printing it or using `isinstance()` to verify your expectation? Please note: a [mcve] should have enough detail for us to reproduce the issue, including `calculate` and/or `game_state`

Comment: I am trying, but it prints out nothing. That might point to it being an empty string.

Comment: @G.Anderson Those are passed into the function. It includes those.

Comment: Concatenating it shows that it is in fact an empty string.

Comment: "dictionary called game_state which is updated by a function"...your code shows that you are rather _overwriting_ `game_state` with the function output, not updating it. Did you mean to use [dict.update()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) rather than assigning it with `=`?

Comment: @G.Anderson Nah, game state should be overriding it. I guess that would make sense, but that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right in front of me. I was passing in the input first, meaning that empty input was overwriting the game state. It should have been `calculate(game_state, c)`.